# In dialogflow chatbot can I do with pre-populated question

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want chatbot like I open the chat window it's automatically multiple questions that have come to the window.possible with Dialogflow if yes then how it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

A chatbot is meant to be interactive unless user started the chat conversation, you should not do that. Better make a conversational tree and make a user start a conversation and have questions.

I see a lot of question-related to dialog flow and google assistant when are building assistant, we need to think a conversational design paradigm instead of app paradigm, that we are used for a long time.

The Assistant is meant to be conversational for a user to deliver the right experience. Due to that, you will find a lot of things we can not do with google assistant explicitly like sending a notification. This is not a conversational design pattern.

So, make your assistant more conversational. In those, you will not come an across with such Delima.